# Smooth scrolling on long click inside gridview Android

Tags: android

I have implemented two buttons and a `gridview` inside my layout. My buttons are already handling `click` and `long click event`.

Upon long click I want the `gridview` to scroll to bottom/top according to my button. I am getting it, but I want the scrolling to be smooth. Now upon long click, I am going directly to bottom/top of gridview. I want upon long click, icons should go rapidly which should be visible. I don't want to implement sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
gridView.post(new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    gridView.fullScroll();
  }

});
```